# Is there a way to tell the built in Clock app to start 5 second timer from my app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

My goal is to tell the built in clock app to start a 5 second timer similar.

The expected result: I can start a 5 second timer from my app.

The actual result: Can't open the Clock app.

What I've tried:

1. say "Hey Siri, start 5 second timer"

```
            Button("Start 5 seconds timer", action: {
                if let url = URL(string: "clock-timer://") {
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .tint(.green)
```